# Hibernate: Deleting parent entity triggers update query on children

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, cascade

**The situation**

I have a parent-child pair of JPA entities.
The parent is called JobTemplate and refers to the child as:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "job_template_id")
private List<ChecklistTemplateEntry> checklistEntries = new ArrayList<>();
```

The child is called ChecklistTemplateEntry and refers to its parent like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "job_template_id")
private JobTemplate jobTemplate;
```

In the mySQL server, there is a cascading setup. The creation command of the child table states:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (job_template_id) REFERENCES job_template(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The cascading works fine if I delete the entity by manually typing the sql commands.

**The problem**

When I try to delete the parent entity via JPA (spring boot repository) by calling

```
jobTemplateRepo.delete(jobTemplateToDelete); //from CrudRepository
```

JPA triggers an update query on the child table:

```
update checklist_template_entry set job_template_id=null where job_template_id=?
```

This query is not accepted by mySQL, since job_template_id has a NOT NULL rule (for good reason). 
The result is that I cannot delete my entity. I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'job_template_id' cannot be null
```

**The goal**

I want to use the JPA cascading from the parent to child on create/update operations. But when deleting a parent entity, I want JPA to only trigger a delete query on that entity and not try to update the children, since this causes problems and  mySQL will take care of that anyway.

**What I have tried**

- Various combinations of cascading, including ALL, all except remove etc.
- Enabling/disabling lazy loading on both sides.

Comment: I think you miss the „mappedBy“ argument on one side of the bidirection

Comment: @MartinFrey you just saved my day! Replacing the JoinColumn annotation with a mappedBy parameter in the OneToMany annotation in the parent entity class solved my problem.

Comment: have you tried  to orphanRemoval = true to orphanRemoval = false? The database is handling that now.

Comment: @MartinFrey Can you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted aswer?
Thanks

Comment: @PeterHe If I am not mistaken, orphanRemoval is useful for update operations, in case you remove entities from the collection. And I need this functionality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the „mappedBy“ argument on one side of the bidirectional annotation , effectively creating two unidirectional relations. 
Replace the JoinColumn on one side with a mappedBy argument and you should get the correct delete statements.